# Quartz.NET, NH ISession & Ninject Scope

Tags: nhibernate, scope, ninject, quartz.net

I'm trying to implement a service that will run jobs based on Quartz.Net.  The jobs may have dependencies like IRepository<> and the repository implementation will have a NHibernate ISession injected into it.  (Quartz will be hosted in a Windows Service).  Jobs are resolved via a IJob factory implementation that uses Ninject to resolve (currently wrapped in a IServiceLocator implementation).

**Job Scope**

I would like to be able to use Ninject to scope the ISession per Job so that there is one session created per job that may be used in multiple IRepository<>'s .

Not sure if this is possible but am wondering if anyone has experience with this?

Can I somehow use the Job context to create a Scope that is used by Kernel.InScope(???).

**Quartz.Net IJobFactory:**

```
public class JobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    readonly IServiceLocator locator;

    public JobFactory(IServiceLocator locator)
     {
         this.locator = locator;
     }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        try
        {               
            var jobDetail = bundle.JobDetail;
            var jobType = jobDetail.JobType;

            return (IJob)locator.Resolve(jobType);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var se = new SchedulerException("Problem instantiating class", e);
            throw se;
        }
    }
}
```

**Ninject Bindings:**

```
        //Service Locator
        Bind<IServiceLocator>().To<NinjectAdapter>();

        //Quartz Bindings
        Bind<IJobFactory>().To<JobFactory>();

        //NHibernate Bindings
        Bind<ISessionFactory>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<NHibernateConfiguration>().BuildSessionFactory()).InSingletonScope();
        Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());// ToDo: Figure out how to scope session

        //Repository Bindings
        Bind(typeof (IRepository<>)).To(typeof (ReadWriteRepository<>));
```

**Main Execution:**

```
        InitializeIoC();
        scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
        scheduler.JobFactory = ServiceLocator.Resolve<IJobFactory>();
        InitializeJobs();
        scheduler.Start();
```

**Example Job:**

```
public class TestJob3 : IJob
{
    private readonly IRepository<Customer> repo;
    private readonly IRepository<Order> orderRepo;

    public TestJob3(IRepository<Customer> repo, IRepository<Order> orderRepo)
    {
        //orderRepo and repo should have the same ISession

        this.repo = repo;
        this.oderRepo = orderRepo;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Job 3 Created");
    }

    #region Implementation of IJob

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Job 3 Executing");
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            var customer = repo.GetById(1);
            customer.Name = "Blue Goats";
            repo.Save(customer);
            scope.Complete();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

** Repository Snippet: **

```
public class ReadWriteRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IRootEntity
{
    private readonly ISession session;

    public ReadWriteRepository(ISession session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetById(int id)
    {
        var entity = session.Get<TEntity>(id);
        return entity;
    }

    public virtual TEntity Save(TEntity entity)
    {
        session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Thanks for taking the time!

**Update**
I ended up using Remo's suggestion and am using InCallScope():

```
Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).InCallScope();
```

The way I like to think of it (correct or not?) is everything from the "initial" get reuses the same items throughout the dependency tree

Comment: Can you post your solution? I'm with the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use InCallScope

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope/wiki/InCallScope

Comment: I am currently using an Activation Block which seems to be working but I will give the InCallScope extension a try. Thanks!

Comment: Remo, can you post your solution using Activation Block?

Comment: @MuriloLima I haven't a solution for this using Activation Block. I wouldn't use that.

Comment: @MuriloLima - In the end I took Remo's suggestion and am using InCallScope which is working great.
Bind<ISession>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).InCallScope();